# Wordpress: theme folder level issue

Tags: database, wordpress, themes, directory

I have installed a theme like this: 
    wp-content/themes/themename-main/themename-theme
Installation worked fine, I began editing my site, that was good. But, I faced a problem with navbar menu that didn't display my menus, so I went to the theme provider site, and they said that theme must be installed as follow:

wp-content/themes/themename-theme and not wp-content/themes/themename-main/themename-theme

So I decided to move wp-content/themes/themename-main/themename-theme
to themes folder and reinstall my theme. Since I've done this, it has messed up with images and content, that disappeared.
How can I solved that ? I just changed the folder level of themename-theme in wp-content/themes

Big thanks in advance

Comment: Paragraphs,use them.

Answer (score 0):

If you revert back to another theme, does the issue still persist?
If the images and content are back in place and are showing then it is most likely a theme issue.

if you have any knowledge of CSS then I would suggest that you go to the stylesheet and look for the .navbar or .navigation depending on what they are using.
(Could also be #navbar or #navigation)

if you menu's aren't showing then it will be in the Stylesheet where it hides the lower level tears. Check for code set to display:none or visibility:hidden and change those attributes and see if the menu shows.

Removing sections of css code and then re-adding them will not mess your site out as long as you place it back correctly.

This sounds like a Stylesheet error to me and if so then the only one that can help you are the Devs.

Also if you have another site then you can try and test it there and see if it has the same problem which will determine a fault with the theme.